# Cannot start Kestrel on production machine IServiceCollection remains null

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration-files, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

Trying to host my webapi on the production machine but there, all DI services remains null. And I get the `NullReferenceException` everywhere I try to access the `services` variable inside the `Startup` class.

The exception points the line where I'm adding the context. `services.AddDbContext(x=>x.UseMySql(...))`. If I remove this line, then It jumps to the `services.AddAutoMapper()` and so on.

Note that this occurs only on the production machine. Everything is pretty cool on my dev machine.

Am I missing a config file (`appsetting.json` and `appsetting.dev.json` are both identicall) OR is there another cause?

Answer (score 0):

Really had hard time solving this issue! I had to navigate to the folder and run `dotnet myApi.dll` instead of using the path `dotnet /var/apps/myapi/myApi.dll`.

Not sure but It seems like the cli is looking for a config file in the directory from within it's being called